# How to render a simple html file in localhost

Tags: apache2, php

I am going through the David Malan lecture on *php*.
So I have created a simple `google.html` file on `/public_html/google.html`

which is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style = "text-align: center">
    <h1>Google</h1>
    <form action = "http://www.google.com/search" method = "get">
      <input name = "q" style = "width: 400px" type = "text">
      <br>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Google Search">
      <input type = "submit" value = "I am feeling lucky">
    </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I tried to open *http://localhost/~anupam/google.html*, I got the

> ERROR 404
>
> Not Found
>      The requested URL /~anupam/google.html was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Why am I unable to display it through localhost? I am running apache2.

Comment: is mod_userdir enabled in apache?

Comment: What if you try with `http://localhost/google.html` ?

Comment: Also, if you want to go with userdir, you need to put the files in `/home/YOUR_LOGIN/public_html/`, not in `/public_html/`.

Comment: Have you set up apache to use `/public_html`? Do you mean `/public_html` as you have written or is it `~/public_html`? What is this lecture you're talking about? What does it suggest you do?

Comment: when I tried toEnable Apache2 Userdir Module in Ubuntu Server,I got the following:   anupam@JAZZ:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
                                                                         [ OK ]
what does this error means??

Comment: thanx @Jan,, it worked now,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `mod_userdir` is enabled: `ls -l /etc/apache2/mods-enabled | grep userdir`.

If it isn't, enable it using `a2enmod userdir`.
After restarting apache, files in `/home/<user>/public_html` are served.